# Can't access variable outside of JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/postalcode.gp?format=json', function(data) {
    console.log(data.geoplugin_postCode);
    var zipCode = data.geoplugin_postCode;
    alert(zipCode);
});
alert(zipCode);
```

for some reason when I do that alert below,

```
alert(zipCode)
```

I get undefined. I need the zipCode to be accessible outside of jQuery. I get the alert for zipCode inside the getJSON.

Comment: that's not how JS works. It's all async and event driven. Whatever is inside the `function(data)` body will get executed after your `alert` outside of the function

Comment: This is because the code you posted is async.  Read up on async/await and callback functions.

Comment: See the answer to this SO question for a good explainer on async JS : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)